# What BIOS settings must I change on a Compaq dc5750 small form factor to install Ubuntu?

Tags: installation, compaq

HP Compaq dc5750 small form factor Athlon 64 X2 3800+ 2.0GHz 2GB 160GB

On starting the system it displayed this message:

> If you are running Unix, you need to configure your system using the
>   computer setup utility (F10)

Attempts to install 12.04 64 bit from a USB flash stick cause this message:

> usi-partman crashed
>
> usi-partman failed with error code 10...

I assume there is a connection between the two. Which settings need to be changed?

Answer (score 2):

The installer error you encountered indicate a failure to access you hard disk(s) for partitioning. This may be due to wrong or not working settings in the BIOS storage access.

In the HP BIOS configuration tool - running with <kbd>F10</kbd> on boot - you may find this in the *Storage -> Storage Options -> SATA Emulation* menu. Remember the settings there and try with `IDE`.

Comment: The value is `Legacy Mode IDE`. What is "try with `IDE`"?

Comment: @C.W.HolemanII: we can't possibly know here what settings are allowed in the BIOS of your machine here but we do suspect that the failure to partition may be related to a malfunctioning or wrong setting in the BIOS hard disk SATA emulation. We might be wrong, but it's definitely worth to have a look at these settings.